# When to expect the results of the Ubuntu App Showdown Community Vote?

Tags: application-development

The Vote is closed since the 29th of Aug.

Is everything OK?
Shouldn't we be aware of the results already?

I thought the counting was done automatically from the site that the voting was taking place. I understand that the applications have to result into the Ubuntu Software Center, but I find that anything more than 3 days is excessive. 9 have passed.

Any announcements yet?

Comment: Please be patient. I don't think it is such as easy as just the counting.

Comment: Thanks, but what else remains?

Comment: Also, it also takes the judges to determine the final result, I think.

Comment: It's a community vote, so the judges were the people who voted, actually. The previous judges (on the "normal" vote) cannot decide this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will announce the winners as soon as they are ready to be published in the Software Center.

Vote was closed on the 29th and the votes have been counted already. It just takes some time to do the technical review, fixes (if necessary) and developer communication to get the winner's apps into the Software Center.

We are aware that this process causes unwanted delays, and we're actively working towards improving it. If you are interested, we're also soon going to announce a proposal for a more streamlined process for 3rd party apps to be published.

*Note:* Essentially, @Tom Brossman's answer is correct, as we're going to announce them as soon as possible. But note that as mentioned in the community vote start blog post, we decided to start the vote without blocking on all apps having gotten into the Software Center. This means that we're not using the public ratings and reviews Software Center API (but the results will be equally public).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, David, but why shouldn't we know the results and just wait to try them out through the software center :D ?

Comment: We want both the users who want to install the applications and the app developers the best experience possible, hence the requirement is to have them installable from the Software Center ready for the announcement.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to assume that 3 of the applications that are in the state 'Published' here: https://trello.com/board/ubuntu-arb-submissions/4fee2215cee295013c0862ba have won the community vote?

Comment: You should feel free to guess, but the final winners will only be disclosed in the public announcement :)

Comment: 13 days and counting....

Answer (score 0):

**Soon**, but that's not the answer you are looking for. There is no specific date or time-frame given on the [detailed FAQ page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/) for the contest, it only says:

> Community vote counting: at the end of the voting week, votes will be
> counted using the public ratings API
>
> The application with the highest average rating and the highest rating total will win the community prize
>
> In case of a draw, the distribution of rating values in the histogram will be used to decide the winner

To learn the results, either keep checking the [developers home page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/), or subscribe to the [Ubuntu App Developers Twitter feed](http://twitter.com/ubuntuappdev).

The bottom of the rules page says the contest is 'governed by the laws of England'. I did a search and found [this quite comprehensive page](http://www.out-law.com/page-6780) which describes the rules of running a competition in Great Britain, which would apply here.